# CodeIgniter controller/view dilemma

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a simple register/login system and it (I think) works well so far.

Now I want to implement some of it's functions to my site.

**controllers/main.php**:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $this->load->view('home.php');
    }
}
```

**views/home.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <?php if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')): ?>

        logged in as: <?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></br>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'login/logout'; ?>">Logout</a>

    <?php else: ?>

        not logged in</br></br>

        <?php echo form_open('login'); ?>
        <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Login" />
        </br>
        <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </br></br>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign in" /></div>
        <?php echo form_error('login_validation'); ?>
        </form>

    <?php endif ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Is this the right way of doing things in CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For controller part instead of using the home(), you can directly load the view in index() because internally you are navigating from index to home() without any specific reason.

Also the loading view doesn't require ".php" extension in your file and you can do like this:

```
$this->load->view('home');
```

Where home.php is the file located inside application/views/

For showing the error messages, you can use another optimal way by defining the validation rules(in array fromat) inside config/form_validation.php and just require below code to show all messages instead one by one

```
<?php echo validation_errors()?>
```